# Getting different RSS Feed order in different browser+PHP

Tags: php, rss

I'm getting the newest RSS Feed that has been published at http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news using PHP. So the idea here is that everytime http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news has been added to my system, it will get the latest published post.

The problem here is that when I view that RSS Feed in Firefox and Chrome, the result is like this:
[image]

But in IE, the result is like this:
[image: IE Result]

So Basically the result is totally different, which obviously the IE result was the right one(notice the Time below the Post title). However, in my code which looks like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents( 'http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news' );
```

I am also getting the same result in Firefox which leads me on not getting th latest published post of http://sports.espn.go.com/espon/rss/news

Kindly guide me about this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Dunno why this happens, but did you try sorting the result on your own before making the output?

Comment: I really wanted to sort the result by using the date published, but the feed url in my system is dynamic, it's only here that I'm using http://sports.espn.go.com/espon/rss/news as an example. RSS URLs have different format of dates that's why I do not have an idea how to sort them.

Comment: Put them into an array, do a ksort ( or whatever suits your needs the best ) and then do the output.

Comment: You mean, ksort the date published? Can this date format "Tuesday, July 10, 2012 7:27 AM" be KSORTed? That's the date format of http://sports.espon.go.com/espn/rss/news

Comment: Okay, I will try, i'll be back :)

Comment: @DainisAbols I posted an answer, kindly check it.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution but it is giving me an inconsistent result due to the date formats of different RSS Posts

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$arrFeeds = array();
$doc->load( "http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news" );
foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node ) {
    $itemRSS = array(
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue
    );
    array_push( $arrFeeds, $itemRSS ); #store array for comparing purposes
}   

$newArray = array();
foreach( $arrFeeds as $k=>$v ){
    $newArray[$v['date']] = $v;
}

ksort($newArray);
$finalArray = array();
foreach( $newArray as $k=>$v ){
    $finalArray[] = $v;
}
krsort($finalArray);

ItemDebug($finalArray);

function ItemDebug($value){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $value );
    echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

THe result is like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There you go m8, glad to help.

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent results because of the Posts date formats. These are the examples of posts date formats:
Sun, 08 Jul 2012 00:38:59 GMT - Tuesday, July 10, 2012 5:05 AM - Mon, 09 Jul 2012 20:27:30 ED - Tue, 10 Jul 2012 02:05:28 -0400 -  Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:00:56 +0000. The question here is that how would I standardize the date format wherein i'm only getting this to a website which I do not own and control. :(

Comment: I believe you can change the time to a lot nicer view with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php function, that will also allow you to sort it better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: `$new_date = date('d-m-Y H:m:i', strtotime( 'Tuesday, July 10, 2012 7:27 AM' ));
echo $new_date;`

Comment: I hope that would also work on those different kind of formats that i'm getting to those different kinds of Feed Posts. These are the examples of posts date formats: Sun, 08 Jul 2012 00:38:59 GMT - Tuesday, July 10, 2012 5:05 AM - Mon, 09 Jul 2012 20:27:30 ED - Tue, 10 Jul 2012 02:05:28 -0400 - Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:00:56 +0000.

Comment: Should work on pretty much anything. You can just test them out by doing simple echo and checking for the result.

Comment: It doesn't work on this Format: Mon, 09 Jul 2012 20:27:30 ED, it returns 01-01-1970 01:01:00 which is totally farout.

Comment: Because that's not a date format. `Mon, 09 Jul 2012 20:27:30 EDT` is a date format.